# Associate git with solution in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, visual-studio

I noticed the TFS and Ankh (svn) plugins for VS2010 will annotate the `.sln` file with a `GlobalSection` that associates the solution with the corresponding source control provider.  So when opening a solution will automatically tell VS to switch to that SCP.  However the git plugin (combination of "git source control provider" and "git extensions for windows") does not do this.

So whenever I open a git solution, VS just uses whatever the last source control provider I was using the previous time I used VS for *any* solution, so I have to go through the Tools/Options menu and update it manually every time I open a git solution.

Is there a `GlobalSection` that will tell VS to use git, or some other way to allow VS2010 to detect that it's a git repo?

Comment: So the Git Source Control Provider *doesn't* hook itself up as the source control provider?  What *does* it do?

Comment: @Ed It doesn't remember the setting.  Once I set git as the SCP in Tools/Options, it works as it should.  But I have to set it manually each time I open the solution, whereas the other SCP plugins autodetect.

Comment: There are some open issues on the plugin page asking for this kind of behavior. I don't think it exists right now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in .sln files

```
GlobalSection(GitScc) = preSolution
    Git-Managed = True
    Manager = Git Source Control Provider
EndGlobalSection
```

Cheers

Comment: Git source control provider doesn't honor  this section.